# linux ubuntu server, can't complete "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, apt-get

I'va installed ubuntu server 10.41 in Vm ware, and I would like to install the desktop
but each time i try to do the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
this error shows up:

```
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/
libproxy0-o.3.1-ubuntu1-amd64.deb 403 Forbidden [Ip:91.189.92.179 80]

E:ubable to fetch some archives,maybe run apt-get update or try with fix --missing?
```

I tried `fix missing` command but didn't work for the same reason.
I tried to cahnge the proxy like this:

1. changed the proxy in my host computer. (ultra serf)
2. changed the proxy settings in my VM to Bridged And Riplicate physical network Connection
    state.
3. run the command:

   export http-proxy
   http-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:80 
   same problem, so mybe i should change the proxy settings in ubuntu but I don't know how
    By the way the missing file that is refusing to be downlaoded is `38.1KB` and all other files are perfectly downloaded
   so maybe i can just download it in the host(windows xp) and move to ubuntu
    but i don't know where is the directory for the downloaded package `OR` where can i add this file, can any one help me?

Comment: this belongs on Server Fault.

Comment: @cha0site, So is there any other way i can get the desktop for ubuntu server?

Comment: Try switching to a different mirror.

Comment: i dont know how, could you please write me the commands for that? am new to linux, and i have been stuck at this point for 3 days now

Comment: This should be asked on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: why the -1?? i asked this question on several places, and with no answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Find lines containing `us.archive.ubuntu.com`. Replace that with another mirror from the [Ubuntu mirror list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors), say `ubuntu.secs.oakland.edu`.

Good luck!

*Edit:* And don't forget to run `apt-get update`!