# Problems downloading programmes

Tags: software-distribution

I am trying to download some programs(in particular texmaker) but i get this:

```
E: Failed to obtain http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/texmaker/texmaker_4.3-1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: *IP number*]
```

The command i used for download this software is the following:

```
sudo apt-get install texmaker
```

Comment: Ensure your IP address is not black listed. Using the same URL, via a browser I was able to download the file. Do you get the same result from a different IP range? Can you give us an example of how you are accessing it?

Comment: What do you mean with black listed?

Comment: Can you try accessing the file directly from a browser, it should (hopefully) provide a more useful error message?

Comment: i do not know what is a different IP range also. Sorry :(

Comment: ok, now i will try

Comment: Your mirror could also be wrong, please check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051904/linux-ubuntu-server-cant-complete-sudo-apt-get-install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145073/discussion-between-hexie-and-santimirandarp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with this issue, steps to follow:

1 - Download the .deb file

- Manually (use [this link](https://www.tug.org/mactex/))
- Code: `wget ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/…`

2 - Install the package (.deb file)

- sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file (change the path to the correct one)

A question that helped with this can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt).

Answer (score 0):

use wget to download the file on your terminal and use dpkg to install it. Maybe that's some problem on your repo configuration.

Comment: Sorry. i do not know how wget can be used